# does mesos master store information about framework or agents?

Tags: mesos

I need to know that does mesos master manage any state information itself such as number of slaves, frameworks or any information. Or does it leverage zookeeper for all information.

Comment: Zookeeper is the distributed backing store for the mesos cluster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mesos stores cluster data in memory and in a so-called [replicated log](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/replicated-log-internals/). If you are curious, what exactly is persisted across Mesos master failovers, check the [Registry](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/master/src/master/registry.proto) protobuf. Everything else, e.g. allocation information, agents state, is restored from the cluster via re-registering agents and frameworks.

Zookeeper is used for leader election only, Mesos does not store there any data. However some Mesos frameworks, e.g. Marathon, may use Zookeeper as persistent storage. Such Zookeeper cluster is often configured separately to avoid any interference with Mesos.